# Change Package Dimensions On Each Variation of Product Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I am using Prestashop 1.7 to create shop of hydraulics. 
[Site here](http://test.magisterhyd.com)

I need to make different combinations of one product that has some attributes. It's actually done. But package dimensions isn't attribute, so i can't change it to different combo. I suggest an idea if i could create attributes similar to dimensions and then override class that controls getting dimensions from product table to combination attribute value. If i am right, how can i do this?